# how integer get stored in memory in four memory address every i.e. how all 4 addresses are filled by bit?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[3]={0,1,2};
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n\n\n",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2]);
    int i;
    printf("%d  %d\n",a,*(a));
    int * ss=(int *)2686753;
    printf("%d  %d\n",ss,*(ss));
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
2686752
2686756
2686760


2686752  0
2686753  16777216
```

Please explain why 16777216 (or any other value) comes at memory address 2686753.

Comment: please explain how you got this value `2686753` before the program gets executed, so that you hard coded the pointer ss with it??

Comment: sorry now please answer

Comment: This isn't clear.  Surely the answer is simply that an `int` is 4 bytes in size (on your platform)?

Answer (score 0):

The integer `a`, which is 4 bytes, is stored at address 2686752 (..3, ..4, ..5).

When you are reading from address 2686753, you also read the next three bytes ..4, ..5, ..6. The last byte contains garbage, and will cause the output to appear random.

Answer (score 0):

Because array's byte layout on your host seems to be 00 00 00 00, 01 00 00 00, 02 00 00 00. Shift this one left, and you get 00 00 00 01, ..., which is representation of 0x01000000, or 16777216.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is specific enough to "elaborate" more on it. I'd pick a book and get actual questions before asking that wide.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code is performing a non aligned access. Probably not portable.